# Enqueue method in Retrofit doesn't load data in Fragment

Tags: java, android, json, http, retrofit2

I have been struck from the past 3 days and unable to load data on recyclerview in Fragment using retrofit 2.4.0.I can see in terminal that the data is being fetched from the server using realtive url but couldn't populate it(means OnReponse and OnFailure is skipped when i debug the code).Furthermore, I can see some garbage values on the application UI. There are some questions that have answered in this regard but none of the solution works for me.Even though I have researched on the github but haven't found any solution there. Uptill now, I have following code.

```
public interface UserAPIEndPoint {
    @GET("posts")
    Call<List<Post>> getAllUsers();
}
```

Following is the Retrofit Instance

```
public class RetrofitInstance {
    public static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String base_Url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){
        if (retrofit == null){
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(base_Url)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Here is the Fragment class

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Post> user;
    private PostAdapter userAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    View rootView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message,container,false);
        loadJSON();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void loadJSON() {
        try {
        UserAPIEndPoint userAPIEndPoint= RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(UserAPIEndPoint.class);
        Call<List<Post>> userlist = userAPIEndPoint.getAllUsers();
//        userlist.execute();
    userlist.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                user = response.body();
                recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                userAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(),user);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Post.class is converted through pojo2schema.
RecyclerAdapter is as follow.

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Post> posts;
    private Context mcontext;

    public PostAdapter(Context context,List<Post> post){
        this.posts = post;
        this.mcontext =context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_post,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.userid.setText(String.valueOf(posts.get(position).getUserId()));
        holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(posts.get(position).getId()));
        holder.title.setText(posts.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.body.setText(posts.get(position).getBody());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView userid,id,title,body;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userId);
            id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.body);

        }
    }

}
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scratchnavigation"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.4.0-alpha01"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'
    implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.4.0'
}
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because it is an async network call. Your creating everything in a different thread.

There are 2 ways to solve this.

1.) Try creating a handler to post on the main thread that the dataset has changed something like

```
        Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            userAdapter = new PostAdapter(user);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            if (userAdapter != null) {
                userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(userAdapter);
                recyclerView.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(userAdapter.getItemCount());
            }
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(userAdapter.getItemCount());
        }
    });
}
```

2.) In the onCreateView assign the recyclerView and Adapter So it looks like:

```
    public class MessageFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Post> user;
    private PostAdapter userAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    View rootView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message,container,false);
        
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        userAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), null);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        
        loadJSON();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void loadJSON() {
        try {
            UserAPIEndPoint userAPIEndPoint= RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(UserAPIEndPoint.class);
            Call<List<Post>> userlist = userAPIEndPoint.getAllUsers();
            userlist.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                    user = response.body();
                    userAdapter.setData(user);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can then also amend the PostsAdapter for that method

```
    public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Post> posts;
    private Context mcontext;

    public PostAdapter(Context context,List<Post> post){
        this.posts = post;
        this.mcontext =context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_post,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.userid.setText(String.valueOf(posts.get(position).getUserId()));
        holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(posts.get(position).getId()));
        holder.title.setText(posts.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.body.setText(posts.get(position).getBody());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }
    
    public void setData(@NonNull List<Posts> list){
        if(list.size() > 0) {
            posts = list;
        }
        this.noftifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView userid,id,title,body;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userId);
            id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.body);

        }
    }

}
```